# Place Highstock inside own SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, charts, highcharts

Here is my problem:

I want to place a chart from highchart as an svg into my own svg (place the chart on a svg map).

I already found this solution on stackoverflow:
[Place Highstock inside a SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678656/place-highstock-inside-a-svg)

```
$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {
        // Create a hidden and not attached div container.
        var div = $('<div>This is an hidden unatached container.</div>');

        // Create the chart
        div.highcharts('StockChart', {

            chart: {
                width: 480,
                height: 400,
                events: {
                    load: function () {
                        // If hidden div was generated, take the svg content and put it into svg.
                        var stockSvg = $('svg', this.container);

                        var svgObj = $('#mySvg').svg();

                        // Force position of highstock
                        stockSvg.attr('x', 20);
                        stockSvg.attr('y', 30);

                        // Replace ugly rect with highstock
                        $('#container', svgObj).replaceWith(stockSvg); 
                    }
                }
            },

            series : [{
                name : 'AAPL',
                data : data,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }]
        });        

    });
```

The example works fine for placing the chart on my own map (svg - build a  element with `id="container"`, which will be replaced with the generated svg chart). But it uses a chart, which is only an example and is not generated in the same way as the examples from highchart which I want to use. This is the code I want to use to generate the chart:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Jan',
            'Feb',
            'Mar',
            'Apr',
            'May',
            'Jun',
            'Jul',
            'Aug',
            'Sep',
            'Oct',
            'Nov',
            'Dec'
        ],
        crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

    }, {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

    }, {
        name: 'London',
        data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

    }, {
        name: 'Berlin',
        data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

    },
     {
        type: 'spline',
        name: 'Average',
        data: [3, 2.67, 3, 6.33, 3.33],
        marker: {
            lineWidth: 2,
            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
            fillColor: 'white'
        }
    }
    ]
});
});
```

tl;dr: The example code, which I found on Stack Overflow (By the Way: Thank you Green Rover and Sebastian Bochan) works fine but I can't transform it into a form usable within my own code.

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: After nearly 6 hours i still didnt get it. Here is my attempt: